# Mixed content on subdomain

Tags: redirect

cancel
How to Format

► put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces

► basic HTML also allowed

formatting help »
asking help »

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your server configuration, it doesn't support SSL for the subdomain.

Comment: I didn't get the error about too many redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving out the `http:` and `https:` prefixes entirely. For instance, you have code like:

```
function Wo_Ajax_Requests_File(){
    return "http://social.searchika.com/requests.php"
}
```

and CSS like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansLight;
    src: url("http://social.searchika.com/themes/wowonder/fonts/OpenSansLight/OpenSansLight.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Change that to:

```
 function Wo_Ajax_Requests_File(){
    return "//social.searchika.com/requests.php"
 }

@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSansLight;
    src: url("//social.searchika.com/themes/wowonder/fonts/OpenSansLight/OpenSansLight.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

If you leave out the protocol, it automatically uses the same protocol as the page itself.

Or you can simply rewrite everything to use `https:`. You only get the "Mixed content" error when you try to load HTTP content from an HTTPS page. There's no problem going the other way.

In your PHP, don't bother checking `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`. Just put the `https:` URL in the config file, and always redirect to that URL.